# Publishing a thread on twitter

Tags: support, search, advertising, markdown, tagging

How was the link http://twitter.com/#!/StackEnglish/status/33529347939770368 made/taken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This relatively new feature was announced on the stackoverflow blog: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/

Answer (score 0):

> [@vgv8 To link to a specific tweet,
>   click the 'time' link](http://twitter.com/#!/Wedge/status/34583251410493440)

That simple